# FireStore not return all results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to get data from firestore, pretend that I have 10 documents in a collection. after that I must get data inside every document, so I save data in ArrayList. But FireBase never return all documents in a collection. Sometimes it returns only 5 ,6 docs in collection that has 10 docs.

my fireBaseUtil :

```
fun getDocumentByQueryAList( idQuery: List<String>, callBack: (ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>) -> Unit) {
        val listDocumentSnapshot = ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>()
        collRef = fireStore.collection("myCollection")
        val size = idQuery.size
        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val query = collRef.whereEqualTo("fieldQuery", idQuery[i])
            query.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    listDocumentSnapshot.add(document)
                    if (i == size - 1) {
                        callBack.invoke(listDocumentSnapshot)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I log out when size = 10 , but i = 8 it called invoke....

UserRepository:

```
FireBaseUtil.getDocumentByQueryAList{
// myList.addAll(listGettedByCallback)
}
```

->> when I want to have data in my list I call FireBaseUtil.getDocumentByQueryAList. I know firebase return value async but I dont know how to get all my doc then receiver.invoke("callbackValue").
Please tell me is there any solution. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are expecting the queries to be run in order like so:

```
get idQuery[0], then add to list, then
get idQuery[1], then add to list, then
get idQuery[2], then add to list, then
...
get idQuery[8], then add to list, then
get idQuery[9], then add to list, then
invoke callback
```

But in reality, all of the following things happen in parallel.

```
get idQuery[0] (add to list when finished)
get idQuery[1] (add to list when finished)
get idQuery[2] (add to list when finished)
...
get idQuery[8] (add to list when finished)
get idQuery[9] (add to list and invoke callback when finished)
```

If the `get idQuery[9]` finishes before some of the others, you will be invoking your callback before the list is completely filled.

A primitive way to fix this would be to count the number of finished get queries, and when all of them finish, then invoke the callback.

```
fun getDocumentByQueryAList( idQuery: List<String>, callBack: (ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>) -> Unit) {
  val listDocumentSnapshot = ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>()
  collRef = fireStore.collection("myCollection")
  val size = idQuery.size
  val finishedCount = 0
  for (i in 0 until size) {
    val query = collRef.whereEqualTo("fieldQuery", idQuery[i])
    query.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
      for (document in documents) {
        listDocumentSnapshot.add(document)
      }
      
      if (++finishedCount == size) { // ++finishedCount will add 1 to finishedCount, and return the new value
        // all tasks done
        callBack.invoke(listDocumentSnapshot)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this will run into issues where the callback is never invoked if any of the queries fail. You could use a `addOnFailureListener` or `addOnCompleteListener` to handle these failed tasks.

The more correct and proper way to do what you are expecting is to make use of [`Tasks.whenAll`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)), which is used in a similar fashion to how you see JavaScript answers using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). I'm still new to Kotlin syntax myself, so expect the following block to potentially throw errors.

```kotlin
fun getDocumentByQueryAList( idQueryList: List<String>, callBack: (ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>) -> Unit) {
  val listDocumentSnapshot = ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>()
  collRef = fireStore.collection("myCollection")
  val getTasks = new ArrayList<Task<Void>>();
  for (idQuery in idQueryList) {
    val query = collRef.whereEqualTo("fieldQuery", idQuery)
    getTasks.add(
      query.get()
        .onSuccessTask { documents ->
          // if query succeeds, add matching documents to list
          for (document in documents) {
            listDocumentSnapshot.add(document)
          }
        }
    )
  }
  
  Tasks.whenAll(getTasks)
    .addOnSuccessListener { results -> 
      callback.invoke(listDocumentSnapshot)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { errors -> 
      // one or more get queries failed
      // do something
    }
}
```

Instead of using the callback, you could return a Task instead, where the last bit would be:

```
return Tasks.whenAll(getTasks)
  .onSuccessTask { results ->
    return listDocumentSnapshot
  }
```

This would allow you to use the following along with other [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) and [`Tasks`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) methods.

```
getDocumentByQueryAList(idQueryList)
  .addOnSuccessListener { /* ... */ }
  .addOnFailureListener { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: @HoanCong If this solved your problem, don't forget to [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use smth like this using RxJava:

```
override fun getAllDocs(): Single<List<MyClass>> {
    return Single.create { emitter ->
        db.collection("myCollection").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    val list = mutableListOf<MyClass>()
                    documents.forEach { document -> 
                        list.add(mapDocumentToMyClass(document))}
                    emitter.onSuccess(list)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    emitter.onError(exception)
                }
    }
}

private fun mapDocumentToMyClass(documentSnapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot) =
        MyClass(
                documentSnapshot.get(ID).toString(),
                documentSnapshot.get(SMTH).toString(),
                // some extra fields
                null
        )
```

Or smth like this using coroutine:

```
override suspend fun getAllDocs(): List<MyClass> {
    return try {
        val snapshot =
            db.collection("myCollection")
                .get()
                .await()
        snapshot.map {
            mapDocumentToMyClass(it)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw e
    }
}
```

This functions helps you to get all data from one doc